# spark streaming using ConstantInputDStream in java

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

I am trying to use ConstantInputDStream in java spark streaming program, but not able to do so. I am doing:

```
            final SparkConf sparkConf2 = new SparkConf().setAppName("NetworkWordCount");
            final JavaStreamingContext ssc2 = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf2, new Duration(10000));
            final List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
            JavaRDD<Integer> distData = ssc2.sparkContext().parallelize(data);
            final JavaDStream<Integer> numStream = new JavaDStream<Integer>(new ConstantInputDStream<Integer>(ssc2, distData));
```

But the final statement is giving compilation error: "error: constructor ConstantInputDStream in class ConstantInputDStream<'T'> cannot be applied to given types;"

What could be the problem and how to fix that?

Comment: try this ConstantInputDStream(ssc2, distData)

Comment: here is how the constructor is defined as per docs  public ConstantInputDStream(StreamingContext _ssc,
                    RDD<T> rdd,
                    scala.reflect.ClassTag<T> evidence$1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
ClassTag<Integer> classTag = ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Integer.class);
final JavaDStream<Integer> numStream = new JavaDStream<Integer>(new ConstantInputDStream<Integer>(ssc2, distData,classTag));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the API may have changed.  I took your code as my starting place and added Vishnu's answer and ended up with this:

```
       try (JavaStreamingContext streamCtxt = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkContext, new Duration(1000))) {
            final List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
            JavaRDD<Integer> distData = streamCtxt.sparkContext().parallelize(data);
            ClassTag<Integer> evidence = ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Integer.class);
            ConstantInputDStream<Integer> integerConstantInputDStream =
                    new ConstantInputDStream<>(streamCtxt.ssc(), distData.rdd(), evidence);
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
            final JavaDStream<Integer> javaDStream = JavaDStream.fromDStream(integerConstantInputDStream, evidence);
            javaDStream.foreachRDD(r -> list.addAll(r.collect()));
            streamCtxt.start();
            streamCtxt.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(2000);
            streamCtxt.stop();
            log.info("here is the list: " + list.stream().map(j->String.valueOf(j)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));       
        }
```

The output is:

```
here is the list: 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5
```